# soap error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I encounter this error when sending a SOAP request with the PHP `SoapClient`:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/phpwebservice/soap-client.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('getCatalogEntry', Array)
#2 /var/www/phpwebservice/soap-client.php(6): SoapClient->getCatalogEntry('catalog1')
#3 {main} thrown in /var/www/phpwebservice/soap-client.php on line 6
```

the script works fine when moving the files directly under the `/var/www/` meaning:

```
http://localhost/soap-client.php
```

but when I move it to a sub-folder called `phpwebservice` that error appears. It doesn't matter if the sub-folder is like this:

```
http://localhost/phpwebservice/soap-client.php
```

or if I made a VirtualHost for it:

```
http://phpwebservice/soap-client.php
```

the content of `soap-client.php`:

```
    $client     = new SoapClient("catalog.wsdl");
    $catalogId      = 'catalog1';
    $response       = $client->getCatalogEntry($catalogId);
    echo $response;
```

soap-server.php:

```
    function getCatalogEntry($catalogId){
    if($catalogId == 'catalog1')
            return  "<html>
                <head>
                    <title>catalog</title>
                </head
                <body>
                <p> </p>
                    <table border=1>
                    <tr>
                        <th>catalogid</th>
                        <th>journal</th>
                        <th>section</th>
                        <th>edition</th>
                        <th>title</th>
                        <th>author</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>catalog1</td>
                        <td>ibm developerworks</td>
                        <td>xml</td>
                        <td>october 2005</td>
                        <td>jaxp validation</td>
                        <td>brett mclaughlin</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>";
elseif($catalogId == 'catalog2')
    return  "<html>
                <head>
                    <title>catalog</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p> </p>
                    <table border=1>
                        <tr>
                            <th>catalogid</th>
                            <th>journal</th>
                            <th>section</th>
                            <th>edition</th>
                            <th>title</th>
                            <th>author</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>catalog1</td>
                            <td>ibm developerworks</td>
                            <td>xml</td>
                            <td>july 2006</td>
                            <td>the java xpath api</td>
                            <td>elliotte harold</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>";
    }
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    $server = new soapserver("catalog.wsdl");
    $server->addfunction("getCatalogEntry");
    $server->handle();
```

catalog.wsdl:

```
   <?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?>
   <definitions name='Catalog'
   targetnamespace='http://phpwebservice/catalog'
   xmlns:tns='http://phpwebservice/catalog'
   xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
   xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
   xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
   xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
   xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>
   <message name='getCatalogRequest'>
    <part name='catalogId' type='xsd:string'/>
   </message>
   <message name='getCatalogResponse'>
    <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
   </message>
   <portType name='CatalogPortType'>
    <operation name='getCatalogEntry'>
                <input message='tns:getCatalogRequest'/>
        <output message='tns:getCatalogResponse'/>
    </operation>
   </portType>
   <binding name='CatalogBinding' type='tns:CatalogPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
    <operation name='getCatalogEntry'>
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:phpwebservice-catalog#getCatalogEntry'/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:phpwebservice-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </input>
        <output>
                    <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:phpwebservice-catalog' encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </output>
    </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name='CatalogService'>
    <port name='CatalogPort' binding='CatalogBinding'>
        <soap:address location='http://phpwebservice/soap-server.php'/>
   </port>
   </service>
   </definitions>
```

thanx.

Comment: I wonder where are the `soap-server.php`, `catalog.wsdl` and `soap-client.php` files located now, and where you'd want them to be?

Comment: @raina77ow they are all under the same folder /var/www/phpwebservice/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind i just remove the /catalog from every line that it's in from the wsdl file,
everything works fine now thanx anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the development environment, it's better to set `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0` in `php.ini`. Otherwise you have to manually delete WSDL cache after doing any changes to WSDL file (generally located in the directory defined by `soap.wsdl_cache_dir`)

You may also refer to: [SoapFault exception: Could not connect to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318870/soapfault-exception-could-not-connect-to-host)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue for a particular SOAP service when [connection_timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) was not specified in my `SoapClient` options. Setting the timeout to 1 fixed the issue for me.

```
$wsdl = 'https://...';
$options [
  'trace' => true,
  'exceptions' => true,
  'connection_timeout' => 1
];
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```