# How to fetch data from wsdl file in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have wsdl file and 3rd party api. We want to fetch data from 3rd party and show on my website we have username and password but we are new in soap api. how to connect with authentication in soap api and fetch data from wsdl file.

We are trying to fetch but this error is showing :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/examin8/public_html/CI/soap/client.php:42 
Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://119.73....', 'urn://119.73.25...', 1, 0) 
#1 /home/examin8/public_html/CI/soap/client.php(42): SoapClient->__soapCall('RealTimePriceDa...', Array) 
#2 /home/examin8/public_html/CI/soap/sevice.php(11): client->getDetails(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/examin8/public_html/CI/soap/client.php on line 42
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
class client{
    public function __construct() {
        $param = array("location" => "https://119.73.253.101:9514/emcdsvc/",
            "uri" => "urn://119.73.253.101:9514/emcdsvc/",
            "trace" => 1);
        $this->instance = new SoapClient(NULL,$param);

        $auth_param = new stdClass();
        $auth_param->username = "env_solution";
        $auth_param->password = "Password1";

        $header_param = new SoapVar($auth_param, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

        $header = new SoapHeader("soap", "authenticate", $header_param, FALSE);

        $this->instance->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

        try {
            $date_array = array("date" => date("dd-mm-yyyy"));
            $result = $this->instance->__soapCall("RealTimePriceDataWebService", $date_array);;
            print_r($result);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$client = new client;
```

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410658/php-soapclient-soapfault-exception-could-not-connect-to-host)

Comment: It's not working connection is not established, page is continue loading and after that it show above error. this error is show if I try with try catch method "Could not connect to host"

Comment: check your outgoing connection is on ? ping that address from CMD

Comment: Not Working 

shoaib@shoaib-desktop:~$ ping https://119.73.253.101:9514/emcdsvc/
ping: unknown host https://119.73.253.101:9514/emcdsvc/
shoaib@shoaib-desktop:~$ ping https://119.73.253.101:9514
ping: unknown host https://119.73.253.101:9514
shoaib@shoaib-desktop:~$ ping https://119.73.253.101
ping: unknown host https://119.73.253.101
shoaib@shoaib-desktop:~$ ping https://119.73.253.101
ping: unknown host https://119.73.253.101
shoaib@shoaib-desktop:~$ ping https://119.73.253.101:9514/emcdsvc/
ping: unknown host https://119.73.253.101:9514/emcdsvc/

Comment: check [this site](http://portquiz.net:1234/). check your Outgoing port is working or not ?

Comment: outgoing port is working